# how to declare" class hierarchy atrribute " in weka

Tags: weka, arff

I try to use Weka to create .arff file and run on CLUS.
But i have a problem with hierarchy atrribute.

> @attribute 'class hierarchical' {Dummy,Top/Arts/Animation,Top/Arts}

I create .arff by this Code.

```
    // 1. set up attributes
    attributes = new FastVector();
    // - numeric
    int NumericAttSize=0;
    for(String word : ListOfWord)
    {
        if(word.length()>1)
        {
            attributes.addElement(new Attribute(word));
            NumericAttSize++;
        }
    }
    // - nominal
    attVals = new FastVector();
    attVals.addElement("Dummy");
    for (String branch : ListOfBranch)
    {
           attVals.addElement(branch);
    }
    attributes.addElement(new Attribute("class hierarchical", attVals));


    // 2. create Instances object
    dataSet = new Instances("training", attributes, 0);


    // 3. fill with data
    for(String DocID : indexTFIDF.keySet())
    {
        values = new double[dataSet.numAttributes()]; 

        for(String word : ListOfWord)
        {
            int index = ListOfWord.indexOf(word);
            if(indexTFIDF.get(DocID).containsKey(word))
                values[index]=indexTFIDF.get(DocID).get(word);
        }
        String Branch = DocDetail.get(DocID).get("1");
        values[NumericAttSize]= ListOfBranch.indexOf(Branch)+1;
        dataSet.add(new Instance(1.0,values));
    }
    ArffSaver arffSaverInstance = new ArffSaver(); 
    arffSaverInstance.setInstances(dataSet);
    arffSaverInstance.setFile(new File("training.arff")); 
    arffSaverInstance.writeBatch();
```

then when I run "training.arff" in CLUS, I got this error message:

> Error: Classes value not in tree hierarchy: Top/Arts/Animation (lookup: Animation, term: Top/Arts, subterms: Animation})

I think the problem is how i declare hierarchical attribute as a nominal attribute, but I have no other ideas how to declare this attribute.

Every suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to an example in the Clus manual (which is in [this zip](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/clus/download.php) in `/Clus/docs/clus-manual.pdf`) a hierarchical attribute should be formatted as follows:

```
@ATTRIBUTE class hierarchical rec/sport/swim,rec/sport/run,rec/auto,alt/atheism
```

So in your case you should remove the quotes around `'class hierarchical'` and remove the curly braces `{}` around your values resulting in:

```
@ATTRIBUTE class hierarchical Dummy,Top/Arts/Animation,Top/Arts
```

Also, if you have multi-label data (i.e., multiple labels per data sample), then you can separate multiple hierarchical values using `@`, as follows:

```
@DATA
1,...,1,rec/sport/run@rec/sport/swim
```

Comment: how WEKA generate

@ATTRIBUTE class hierarchical rec/sport/swim,rec/sport/run,rec/auto,alt/atheism

Comment: Weka can't always be used to generate .ARFF files which will be used by Clus. For example, Clus added the `hierarchical` attribute itself and Weka is unaware of the notation used by this type of attribute. So you should either create the .ARFF with Weka and then (manually or automatically) edit the .ARFF to conform to Clus' notation, or you shouldn't use Weka to create the .ARFF and write a script yourself which makes the .ARFF.